# display two columns in the block

Tags: css

I need some help with a problem.

There is a list in the block certain height. Height more than the height of the list, so it is [displayed in 2 columns](http://jsfiddle.net/7tT2G/).

I did not get to do so at first filled the first column of the list items, then the second. [it looks like this](http://prozaik.16mb.com/html5_2/lists/lists.png)

css

```
.wrap{

}
.wrap ol{
    height: 290px;
    width: 500px;
    display: block;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .wrap ol li{
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to use CSS multi-column.

```
.wrap{
  column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/aC4Nc/

To increase compatiblity with old browsers, use this [polyfill](https://github.com/BetleyWhitehorne/CSS3MultiColumn)